# Time complexity of offset in pread?

Tags: c++, c, file, posix

If I call pread in c or c++

```
ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);
```

What is the time complexity of offset? Do we just jump to the offset? Or does the program read in "offset" number of bytes? Is it O(1) or O(offset) to get to the offset?

Comment: It is O(1) complexity

Comment: Note that pread is not part of either Standard C or Standard C++.

Comment: In theory, it depends on the storage medium. For example, if you have data stored on tape, a seek involves actually winding tape from one reel to another with O(N) complexity. With a hard drive it can vary depending on whether the seek involves head movement. On an SSD, it's normally O(1). In actuality, direct use of tape is now sufficiently unusual that you can usually treat it as O(1) fairly safely (but beware that in corner cases it may not be).

Comment: @JerryCoffin The amount of head movement is not a function of `offset`, and it's bounded by the seek time across the entire disk, so it would be considered O(1).

Comment: @Barmar: I can't agree. Assuming the files are reasonably contiguous (which most file systems try to do), the amount of head movement varies directly with the offset. Bounded by time to seek across the disk is roughly like saying all in-memory sorts are O(1) because they're bounded by the time to sort all the items that will fit in memory (or memory +disk with virtual memory). From one perspective, both can be seen as sort of true, but that perspective generally does more to hide than reveal relevant information.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It depends on where the read head happens to be when it starts; it could be right over the sector already, or it could be far away. Also, your I/O is mixed with all the other disk activity on the system, and the disk scheduler will reorder them to optimize head movement. There's very little direct relationship between the offset and the time.

Comment: @Barmar: yet again, the reasoning sounds highly suspect to me. Would you say a sort is O(-N) if I got it to run faster on larger data by killing other apps as it started to sort larger amounts of data? Of course it's not--the sort is still O(N log N) (or whatever), regardless of manipulating other factors in the system.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ignore my point about it being bounded. Why are you assuming that you're moving the head from offset 0 to offset N? Unless the previous read was at offset 0 of the same file, there's no reason to believe that this is where the read head is before you call `pread()`. It could be anywhere on the disk, and the seek time is not directly related to the offset.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single, simple answer.

First, I/O systems can be way too complex, and there are certainly way too many variations for any general statement to be universal.  File systems matter, disk drives matter, RAID configuration - if applicable - matters.  And that's just for simple file systems such as XFS or ext4.  Things get really complex for combined filesystems/volume managers such as ZFS, or complex multi-device high-performance file systems such as GPFS or QFS/SAMFS.  Tape systems and hierarchical storage managers make things even more complex.

Second, the actual pattern of I/O operations matters greatly.  Reading random offsets from an SSD won't impact performance much, while reading random offsets from a spinning disk or a tape will impact performance greatly.  How will any caching impact the performance?  How about optimization strategies such as read-ahead?

So, if you want the answer to

> What is the time complexity of offset? Do we just jump to the offset? Or does the program read in "offset" number of bytes? Is it O(1) or O(offset) to get to the offset?

You need to run your I/O operations on your intended system, benchmark them thoroughly, and see what the characteristics really are.

Or, you can thoroughly describe your system and your intended I/O pattern and someone here can likely provide you some estimates on the likely behavior of your system under that load.  And should you then benchmark your I/O patterns on that system, those estimates might even be somewhat correct.

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotic notation cannot be applied to finite devices, as it describes the trend for the parameter going to infinity. Offset is bounded and as such your question is irrelevant.

---

If your question is more practical, then a direct access medium (magnetic disk, flash disk, optical disk) can feature constant-time access or an access time that is a (complicated but slowly growing) function of the distance to the previous access. Sequential access media (magnetic tape, punched tape...) will probably have a time roughly proportional to the distance to the previous access, unless a rewind is necessary.

In any case, precise analytical relations are unavailable.

---

More generally speaking, access to a huge storage space may be considered to behave exponentially in terms of the offset, because you traverse a hierarchy of slower and slower memory devices (from ultrafast cache down to disk files, then to external and even off-line/high latency devices such as tape jukeboxes, then operators called to physically mount a tape...). But this takes us far from `pread` :-)